# docker : docker pull incendonet/centos7-mono-apache

Tags: docker

Docker is not started even if the subsequent command is executed.

```
docker pull incendonet/centos7-mono-apache
```

Even if you check with `docker ps`, it does not exist.

Please tell me the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Docker will be started after you run below command :

```
docker run -it -d image-name
docker run -it -d incendonet/centos7-mono-apache
```

`docker pull` command just fetches image from docker hub to your server/local machine. But to run it you need to use `docker run`.

Once it is running then it will be shown in your `docker ps` command and you can use below command to get into container's shell :

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash
```